# Native C.dll on Windows referenced by .NET 6 App only works when Visual Studio with C++ Desktop Extension is installed

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, .net-6.0, hid

I use an OpenSource library (https://github.com/libusb/hidapi) to send commands to our device firmware via HID over USB...more precisely I´ve compiled the C-Code of the hidapi-Windows-project and call its native methods by DllImport-Attibute in a Wrapper-Class of my .NET 6 application.
Everything works fine as long as I have a Visual Studio 2022 with C++ Desktop Development Extension Package installed on the same machine where the application runs...

Publishing the whole application (self-contained) to a folder and running it on a machine where no Visual Studio 2022 with C++ Desktop Extension pack is installed the application starts but the HidEnumerate method of the hidapi.dll-Wrapper does not find any HID device...

So I thought the C++ Redistributable 2022 might be missing and installed it but unfortunately no effect...

Does anyone have an idea which Dll(s) or configuration are missing ?

Is it a matter of signing the application to make it work without the Visual Studio context ?

Comment: When a DLL is missing one usually get an error message that tells what is missing. Without the error message or any description of what is happening, it is hard to know. Obviously, we assume that you are building a release version of your application...

Comment: If the dll is missing, the project will not work properly. You can try to download again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint in the comment...the native code was build with Debug-Configuration...after building it in Release-Mode the native lib works fine !

Comment: Fix the exception handling, this is not the kind of mishap that should ever go unreported.